# Space between caption and subfigure

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats, subcaption

I would like to increase the space between each subcaption of subfigure.
Here, I present the code of my figure:

```
  \begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\subfigure[Solution 1 -- $y_1$ is optimized first]{
\label{Mosaics1}
\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tabular}{|
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EDEDED}}c |c|c|cc|c|c|
>{\columncolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}}c |ll}
\cline{1-8}
\cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Apr. & \cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}May & \cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Jun. & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Jul.} & \cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Aug. & \cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Sep. & \cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Oct. & \cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Nov. &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{FCE4D6}Farm 1: $1-5$ \\ \cline{1-8}
(7,1,124.61) & \cellcolor[HTML]{EDEDED}(6,3,96.83) & \cellcolor[HTML]{FCE4D6}(3,1,125.20) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FCE4D6}(5,1,231.00)} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FCE4D6}(2,1,231.36) & \cellcolor[HTML]{FCE4D6}(4,1,128.11) & \cellcolor[HTML]{FCE4D6}(1,1,277.68) & (19,1,148.16) &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{EDEDED}Farm 2: $6-10$ \\ \cline{2-7}
(9,1,195.95) & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(14,1,190.27) & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(20,1,253.24) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(12,1,244.20)} & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(11,1,231.00) & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(16,4,45.16) & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(15,5,44.46) & (13,1,144.52) &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}Farm 3: $11-20$ \\ \cline{2-5} \cline{7-7}
(10,1,138.95) & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(24,1,210.56) & \cellcolor[HTML]{EDEDED}(8,1,125.72) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(23,8,45.39)} & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(22,8,37.47) & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(17,1,212.31) & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFE699}(27,1,356.20) & (18,1,141.13) &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}Farm 4: $21-26$ \\ \cline{1-8}
\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(21,2,190.78) & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(26,1,225.36) & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(25,8,38.09) &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFE699}(29,2,160.48) & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFE699}(28,1,281.15) & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFE699}(30,2,211.50) &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFE699}Farm 5: $27-30$ \\ \cline{1-3} \cline{6-8} 

\end{tabular}}

}\qquad
\subfigure[Solution 2 -- $y_2$ is optimized first]{
\scalebox{0.8}{
\label{Mosaics2}
\begin{tabular}{c|
>{\columncolor[HTML]{FCE4D6}}c |ccccccll}
\cline{1-8}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Apr.} & \cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}May & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Jun.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Jul.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Aug.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Sep.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Oct.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Nov.} &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{FCE4D6}Farm 1: $1-5$ \\ \cline{1-8}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FCE4D6}(1,1,225.79)} & (3,1,127.69) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(14,1,267.51)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(11,2,64.43)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(12,5,35.21)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(17,1,165.25)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EDEDED}(6,1,268.91)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EDEDED}(7,1,123.29)} &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{EDEDED}Farm 2: $6-10$ \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FCE4D6}(2,2,103.13)} & (4,1,179.98) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(15,5,38.64)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(13,1,229.71)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(20,1,218.95)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(18,4,50.39)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EDEDED}(10,1,168.72)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EDEDED}(8,1,137.81)} &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}Farm 3: $11-20$ \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(22,4,83.62)} & (5,1,155.76) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(21,4,113.48)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(16,3,64.08)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(23,4,101.71)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(19,1,138.84)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFE699}(28,2,101.36)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EDEDED}(9,1,244.94)} &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}Farm 4: $21-26$ \\ \cline{1-6} \cline{8-8}
 & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(24,2,105.86) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(25,4,70.86)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFE699}(29,2,146.20)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFE699}(30,2,215.88)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFE699}(27,4,78.20)} &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFE699}Farm 5: $27-30$ \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} \cline{6-8}
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(26,2,125.53)} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  &  \\ \cline{2-2}
\end{tabular}
}
}
\qquad
\subfigure[Solution 3 -- $y_3$ is optimized first]{
\label{Mosaics3}
\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tabular}{ccc|c|ccccll}
\cline{1-8}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Apr.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}May} & \cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Jun. & \cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Jul. & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Aug.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Sep.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Oct.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Nov.} &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{FCE4D6}Farm 1: $1-5$ \\ \cline{1-8}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FCE4D6}(1,1,225.79)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FCE4D6}(2,2,119.17)} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FCE4D6}(5,1,155.61) & \cellcolor[HTML]{FCE4D6}(4,1,186.69) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EDEDED}(6,1,313.93)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EDEDED}(8,1,176.58)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EDEDED}(9,1,250.80)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EDEDED}(10,1,173.52)} &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{EDEDED}Farm 2: $6-10$ \\ \cline{2-8}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FCE4D6}(3,1,110.51)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(11,1,208.55)} & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(20,1,273.68) & \cellcolor[HTML]{EDEDED}(7,1,125.78) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(12,1,263.44)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(18,1,147.12)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(15,2,123.75)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(13,1,122.75)} &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}Farm 3: $11-20$ \\ \cline{1-5} \cline{7-7}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(17,1,185.26)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFE699}(29,1,323.59)} & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(23,1,278.50) & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(16,1,141.37) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(21,1,378.44)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(19,1,138.84)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(26,1,293.84)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(14,1,171.37)} &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}Farm 4: $21-26$ \\ \cline{1-8}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFE699}(30,1,382.24)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFE699}(27,1,350.39) & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(24,1,226.35) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(25,1,376.25)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(22,1,352.87)} &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFE699}Farm 5: $27-30$ \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4} \cline{6-6} \cline{8-8}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFE699}(28,1,283.44)} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  &  \\ \cline{4-4}
\end{tabular}}
}
\qquad
\subfigure[Solution 4 -- compromise between all objectives]{
\scalebox{0.8}{
\label{Mosaics4}
\begin{tabular}{|
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EDEDED}}c |c|c|c|c|c|c|c|ll}
\cline{1-8}
\cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Apr. & \cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}May & \cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Jun. & \cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Jul. & \cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Aug. & \cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Sep. & \cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Oct. & \cellcolor[HTML]{A5A5A5}Nov. &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{FCE4D6}Farm 1: $1-5$ \\ \cline{1-8}
(6,1,251.38) & \cellcolor[HTML]{EDEDED}(9,2,113.21) & \cellcolor[HTML]{EDEDED}(8,2,79.77) & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(11,1,231.00) & \cellcolor[HTML]{FCE4D6}(2,1,240.22) & \cellcolor[HTML]{FCE4D6}(3,1,123.49) & \cellcolor[HTML]{FCE4D6}(1,2,128.44) & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(19,1,173.87) &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{EDEDED}Farm 2: $6-10$ \\ \cline{2-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7}
(7,1,124.61) & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(14,1,190.27) & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(12,1,215.62) & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(17,1,227.84) & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(5,1,142.82) & \cellcolor[HTML]{FCE4D6}(4,1,208.55) & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(18,2,132.00) & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(20,1,163.73) &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}Farm 3: $11-20$ \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} \cline{6-8}
(10,1,127.51) & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(24,1,210.56) & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(16,1,137.94) & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(23,1,363.13) & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(13,1,154.38) & \cellcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7}(15,2,90.67) & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFE699}(27,1,356.20) & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFE699}(28,1,282.30) &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}Farm 4: $21-26$ \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7}
\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(21,1,383.12) & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(26,1,225.36) & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(25,2,169.28) &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFDA}(22,1,299.77) & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFE699}(29,1,320.96) &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFE699}(30,1,380.70) &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFE699}Farm 5: $27-30$ \\ \cline{1-3} \cline{5-6} \cline{8-8}
\end{tabular}}
}
\caption{Scheme for four different solutions determined in the instance with 30 plots}
\label{Mosaics}
\end{figure}
```

(the packages \usepackage{subfigure}, \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} are necessary here)
and the output generated:

[image]

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Based on the arguments, you are using the obsolete subfigure package.  Try using the subcaption package instead, then play with skip option.

Comment: Alternatively, just try adjusting \abovecaptionskip and \belowcaptionskip.